# permanent `chmod` of btrfs top-level directory

Tags: btrfs, chmod

When doing `chmod o+rx /mnt` to a btrfs filesystem, the chmod changes are lost after reboot.

How can I permanently give `o+rx` access to a btrfs top-level directory?